# Module-info.java settings

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-14, intellij-13

Platform - Windows
JAVA-11

module-info.java:

```
module UdemyJavaFX {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires java.desktop;

    opens sample;
}
```

It shows error:

```
Error:(1, 1) java: module UdemyJavaFX reads package java.awt from both java.desktop and java.datatransfer
```

When I created a new project it works fine no error than I figured out error was in Intellij files on further exploring I figured out error was in workspace.xml.

As soon as I copied workspace.xml from new project to this one it works fine.

I was not able to figure out What could be the cause of error and exactly which lines are responsible for it?

Comment: JavaFX surely already requires `java.desktop`, so try removing that.

Comment: Did you use the same JDK in both cases? Were you able to build the project with this error? If issue can be reproduced in an isolated project please provide it to check.

Comment: @Marquis even in removing it , shows error in my view it doesn't requires java.desktop by default

Comment: @Andrey yes i used same javafx and same JDK-11 in both cases